# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings can help me? in json

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $maskapai = $_POST['maskapai'];
     $slotAsal = $_POST['slotAsal'];
     $slotTujuan = $_POST['slotTujuan'];
     $hargaTiket = $_POST['hargaTiket'];

     foreach($bAsal as $dataAsal => $value){
         if($dataAsal = $_POST['slotAsal']){
             $pajakAsal = $value;
        }
    }
    foreach($bTujuan as $dataTujuan => $value){
       if($dataTujuan = $_POST['slotTujuan']){
           $pajakTujuan = $value;
        }
    }

    echo $slotAsal;
    echo $slotTujuan;
    
    $newData = [$maskapai, $slotAsal, $slotTujuan, $hargaTiket];
    $data[] = $newData;
    var_dump($data);
    $daftarData = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($sumber, $daftarData);
    echo json_encode($slotAsal, $slotTujuan);
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiket\ticket.php:93 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiket\ticket.php on line 93

i want to print out my code with encode to json, but what i got is fatal error, and on json the data has not print out, anybody can help me? i got stuck in here

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Would be a good start to read [`json_encode()` in the manual and see how many parameters it accespts and what they do](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: If you are only going to show us a part of the script and an error message that talks about **line 93** it is useful to know which is line 93

Comment: There are a lot of variable in this code we have ___absolutely no knowledge of___

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere previously to the code you show us you have declared `$data` to be a string variable, so now you cannot make it into an array (since PHP7.1 I think)

EG

```
$data = '';

$data = [1,2,3];  // is allowed

$data[] = [1,2,3]  // cause your error
```

So use a new variable name other than `$data`